# jQuery validation is not working in contact form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

I want validation through jQuery. I have two fields name and email. email blank field validation is not working.

Here is my code,

```
<form>
    Name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <span id="nameSpan"></span>
    <br>
    Email:<input type="email" name="email" id="email1"><br>
    <span id="emailSpan"></span>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn">
</form>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email1 = $("#email1").val();

    $("#submitBtn").on("click", function(){
        if(name == '')
        {
            $("#nameSpan").html('Name is required');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#nameSpan").html('');
        }

        if(email1 == '')
        {
            $("#emailSpan").html('Email is required');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#emailSpan").html('');
        }
    });        
});
```

Please guide me where am I wrong. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking values of inputs only once while page load. We need to check them everytime so lets move this part into onclick function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submitBtn").on("click", function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email1 = $("#email1").val();

        if(name == '')
        {
            $("#nameSpan").html('Name is required');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#nameSpan").html('');
        }

        if(email1 == '')
        {
            $("#emailSpan").html('Email is required');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#emailSpan").html('');
        }
    });        
});
```